# how to create two dimensional array knowing only the first column

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a question on how to create a two dimensional array. In my case, I am trying to create a two dimensional array based off of the first column (velocity) and using that to calculate and display numbers in the rest of the columns and the rest of the columns have different degrees, like 25, 45, & 75 degrees. How can I do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code that I have so far:

```
public class Catapult {

static final int ROWS = 5;
static final int COLS = 5;

public static void calculations(int velocity[], int angle[], int testNum){
    int col = testNum - 1;
    for(int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
        scores[row][col] = // initial velocity * sin(2*angle)/g
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Is your difficulty with the mathematics, with creating the two-dimensional array `scores`, with returning that array to the caller of `calculations()`, or something else?

Comment: Do you mean that `scores[i][j]` is calculated based on `velocity[i]` and `angle[j]`?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need this? Such an array would probably only pay off when you use the individual values many hundred times. In all other cases the golden rule is: *Don't store easily recomputable values.*

Here is an alternative:

```
public static double score(int v, int angle) {
    return v * sin(2*angle) / g;
}
```

(Not sure if the types make sense, though this is a different problem.)

And then, later, instead of

```
scores[i][j]
```

you say

```
score(velocity[i], angle[j])
```